# Efficiently inserting default missing rows in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I've got the following `data.table` :

```
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
           wday=c("mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat","mon","tue","thu","fri"),
           val=c(2,3,5,8,6,2,3,4,2,6))

    id wday val
 1:  1  mon   2
 2:  1  tue   3
 3:  1  wed   5
 4:  1  thu   8
 5:  1  fri   6
 6:  1  sat   2
 7:  2  mon   3
 8:  2  tue   4
 9:  2  thu   2
10:  2  fri   6
```

This is the result of an aggregation of another `data.table`. It represents the count (`val`) of a variable depending on the week day (`wday`) for different individuals (`id`). The problem is, during my operations I've lost the week days where the count is 0.

So the question is : how could I update my `data.table` object efficiently by inserting, for each id, as many rows as there are missing week days with `val=0` ?

The result would be the following :

```
    id wday val
 1:  1  mon   2
 2:  1  tue   3
 3:  1  wed   5
 4:  1  thu   8
 5:  1  fri   6
 6:  1  sat   2
 7:  1  sun   0
 8:  2  mon   3
 9:  2  tue   4
10:  2  wed   0
11:  2  thu   2
12:  2  fri   6
13:  2  sat   0
14:  2  sun   0
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward way I could think of right now is to use `expand.grid` to get all combinations and then use that to subset with `allow.cartesian = TRUE`:

```
setkey(dt, "id", "wday")
vals <- c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun")
idx <- expand.grid(vals, unique(dt$id))[, 2:1]
dt[J(idx), allow.cartesian=TRUE]

#     id wday val
#  1:  1  mon   2
#  2:  1  tue   3
#  3:  1  wed   5
#  4:  1  thu   8
#  5:  1  fri   6
#  6:  1  sat   2
#  7:  1  sun  NA
#  8:  2  mon   3
#  9:  2  tue   4
# 10:  2  wed  NA
# 11:  2  thu   2
# 12:  2  fri   6
# 13:  2  sat  NA
# 14:  2  sun  NA
```

Alternatively, it is possible to directly build the `idx` data table with `CJ` :

```
dt[CJ(unique(dt$id),vals), allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arun ! I just edited your answer slightly to mention the possibility to use `CJ` instead of `expand.grid`. Feel free to keep, delete or modify it.

Comment: Oh yes indeed @juba, great! I hadn't used that in a while... thanks for reminding me as well.

Answer (score 1):

One other possilibity with match and ddply :

```
FUN <- function(x) {
y <- x$val[match(c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"), x$wday, nomatch=NA)]
y[is.na(y)] <- 0
y <- data.frame(wday=c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"), val=y)
y
}
ddply(dt, .(id), FUN)
```

Comment: Thanks for the `plyr` solution. I think I'll accept the `data.table` one, but this one works perfectly well, too.